# APN key goes missing from firebase project after adding the same key to multiple projects in firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've set up three firebase projects for Dev, QA and Prod , each one has iOS application setup , when adding the APN key to these projects for push notification , it gets removed from the later one when adding it to the other.

Tried adding the same key to two different firebase projects, but the APN key doesn't exit in two projects, always the key gets removed from one of the projects.
I've attached screenshot with key present

[image]

[image]

I expect that a single APN key can be used for multiple projects in firebase for push notification.

Firebase Push notifications works fine in android